# NOT Exists Function

Tags: ms-access-2010

Request help in below query for "NOT EXISTS" function for MS ACCESS. Below is the query. The data is still getting picked up from the VATExclusion table though it should exclude all those the GLs from GRT_Source table which are avilable in VATExclusion table.

Parameter of exclusion in VATExclusion is GL to be excluded from GRT_Source table if they are avilable in VATExclusion basis VATExclusion.Branch + VATExclusion.GL in range+ VATExclusion.Base_No in range.

Issue is: query is excluding all the GLs from VATExlcution table except for a data coming in criteria for perticualr branch

```
SELECT GRT_Source.LV_ID, GRT_Source.GL_ACCT_ID, GRT_Source.TRAN_CCY_CD, GRT_Source.FUNC_CCY_CD, GRT_Source.LCL_LV_ID, GRT_Source.LCL_GL_ACCT_1, GRT_Source.LV_SUB_DIVN_ID, GRT_Source.ENTRPS_PROD_ID, GRT_Source.GOC, GRT_Source.CPRT_GOC, GRT_Source.CUST_ID, GRT_Source.CUST_ID_TYP_CD, GRT_Source.FYR, GRT_Source.ACTG_PRD_NO, GRT_Source.LCL_CUST_ID, GRT_Source.LCL_PROD_ID, GRT_Source.SUB_GL_FEED_ID, GRT_Source.FRS_BSUNIT_ID, GRT_Source.FDL_ACCT_ID, GRT_Source.FRS_OPER_UNIT_ID, GRT_Source.SRC_SYS_ARRG_ID, GRT_Source.TRAN_CCY_MTD_BAL_AMT, GRT_Source.FUNC_CCY_MTD_BAL_AMT, GRT_Source.RPRT_CCY_MTD_BAL_AMT, Domicile.DO
FROM GRT_Source LEFT JOIN Domicile ON GRT_Source.LCL_CUST_ID=Domicile.LCL_CUST_ID 
WHERE Left(GRT_Source.LCL_GL_ACCT_1,1)="4" AND 
Left(GRT_Source.SUB_GL_FEED_ID,3) Not Like "%ADJ%" And 
Left(GRT_Source.SUB_GL_FEED_ID,3) Not Like "%FRM%" AND
NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from VATExclusion where GRT_Source.LCL_LV_ID=VATExclusion.Branch and GRT_Source.LCL_GL_ACCT_1 between VATExclusion.START_Flexcube_GL and VATExclusion.END_Flexcube_GL AND  GRT_Source.LCL_CUST_ID between VATExclusion.Base_No and VATExclusion.Base_No_End);
```

Comment: You have failed to tell the Query **what** NOT exists ? You can also use NOT IN on a column.

Comment: that issue worked fine... Thanks for looking into but now getting data mismatch issue.. now idea where data mismatch is coming..

Comment: Can you edit your post with the Query you are using now?

Comment: Thanks alot Paul. Really appreciate your help. The issue is resolved :)